# SQL Server 2012 PERCENT_RANK() Exclude NULLS

Tags: sql-server, null

```
SELECT [Cole_Crops], 
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY HUC02 
                            ORDER BY [Cole_Crops]) AS Cole_Crops_PCT_RANK], 
       [Row_Crops], 
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY HUC02 
                            ORDER BY [Row_Crops]) AS Row_Crops_PCT_RANK]            
FROM V012_CDLMAX_09
```

---

How do you exclude NULL values from affecting the PERCENT_RANK in a query with multiple columns to be ranked?

SQL Server 2012 `PERCENT_RANK()` treats NULLS as a real value in the distribution. If there were one column to be ranked, you can simply add a where clause (i.e., `where Cole_Crops IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: I don't think this can be done directly in the select statement.  All of the windowed functions are run against the entire query result set.  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easy fix, use a case statement in your partition clause.

```
CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN_1 IS NULL THEN NULL 
    ELSE PERCENT_RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY 
            CASE 
                WHEN COLUMN_1 IS NULL THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
            END 
         ORDER BY COLUMN_1) 
END AS RANK_COLUMN_1
```

This will rank nulls and non-nulls individually, but the wrapping case statement will display null values as nulls.

Problem solved!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement in your Percent_Rank ORDER BY.  You can make NULL values whatever you want them to be.  Below it is treating all NULL values as 0

```
SELECT [Cole_Crops], 
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY HUC02 
                            ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Cole_Crops] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Cole_Crops] END) AS Cole_Crops_PCT_RANK], 
       [Row_Crops], 
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY HUC02 
                            ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Row_Crops] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Row_Crops] END) AS Row_Crops_PCT_RANK]            
FROM V012_CDLMAX_09
```

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, I am hoping to exclude NULLS  from the distribution entirely so they don't affect the relative ranking. For instance, n=100 with NULLS and n=75 without NULLS. Converting NULL to another value keeps n=100 which changes the percent ranking of the values being examined. 
I hope I understood your idea completely.

Comment: ISNULL([FieldName], 0) would achieve the same result with less typing.  But I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.  @JacamoFinane are you trying to rank only the non-null values in the column?  Are you looking for null records to have no rank at all?

Comment: yes, desire NULL records to have no rank at all. Can be achieved when a single value in the query is to be ranked by using a where clause but troubling when there are 30+ values requiring ranking. Am hoping to avoid separate queries for each ranking. Thank you

Comment: Sorry you can't do this without working around. See this open Connect ticket for more: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/532474

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a condition in PARTITION BY clause:

```
SELECT [Cole_Crops], 
   PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Cole_Crops] is not null, HUC02 
                        ORDER BY [Cole_Crops]) AS Cole_Crops_PCT_RANK], 
   [Row_Crops], 
   PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Row_Crops] is not null, HUC02 
                        ORDER BY [Row_Crops]) AS Row_Crops_PCT_RANK]
FROM V012_CDLMAX_09
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little revision to Wes's answer. It should be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN_1 IS NULL THEN NULL 
    ELSE PERCENT_RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY 
             HUC02
            END 
         ORDER BY COLUMN_1) 
END AS RANK_COLUMN_1
```