# Skip null values when counting with RANK() OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a set of rows, with a field sometimes `null` and sometimes not:

```
SELECT 
   Date, TheThing
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date


Date                     TheThing
-----------------------  --------
2016-03-09 08:17:29.867  a
2016-03-09 08:18:33.327  a
2016-03-09 14:32:01.240  NULL
2016-10-21 19:53:49.983  NULL
2016-11-12 03:25:21.753  b
2016-11-24 07:43:24.483  NULL
2016-11-28 16:06:23.090  b
2016-11-28 16:09:07.200  c
2016-12-10 11:21:55.807  c
```

I want to have a ranking column that counts the non-null values:

```
Date                     TheThing  DesiredTotal
-----------------------  --------  ------------
2016-03-09 08:17:29.867  a         1
2016-03-09 08:18:33.327  a         2
2016-03-09 14:32:01.240  NULL      2 <---notice it's still 2 (good)
2016-10-21 19:53:49.983  NULL      2 <---notice it's still 2 (good)
2016-11-12 03:25:21.753  b         3
2016-11-24 07:43:24.483  NULL      3 <---notice it's still 3 (good)
2016-11-28 16:06:23.090  b         4
2016-11-28 16:09:07.200  c         5
2016-12-10 11:21:55.807  c         6
```

I try the obvious:

```
SELECT 
   Date, TheThing, 
   RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date
```

But `RANK()` counts nulls:

```
Date                     TheThing  Total
-----------------------  --------  -----
2016-03-09 08:17:29.867  a         1
2016-03-09 08:18:33.327  a         2
2016-03-09 14:32:01.240  NULL      3 <--- notice it is 3 (bad)
2016-10-21 19:53:49.983  NULL      4 <--- notice it is 4 (bad)
2016-11-12 03:25:21.753  b         5 <--- and all the rest are wrong (bad)
2016-11-24 07:43:24.483  NULL      7
2016-11-28 16:06:23.090  b         8
2016-11-28 16:09:07.200  c         9
2016-12-10 11:21:55.807  c         10
```

How can i instruct `RANK()` (or `DENSE_RANK()`) to not count nulls?

### Have you tried using a PARTITION?

Why yes! Much worse:

```
SELECT 
   Date, TheThing, 
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY(CASE WHEN TheThing IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date
```

But `RANK()` counts nulls:

```
Date                     TheThing  Total
-----------------------  --------  -----
2016-03-09 08:17:29.867  a         1
2016-03-09 08:18:33.327  a         2
2016-03-09 14:32:01.240  NULL      1 <--- reset to 1?
2016-10-21 19:53:49.983  NULL      2 <--- why go up?
2016-11-12 03:25:21.753  b         3 
2016-11-24 07:43:24.483  NULL      3 <--- didn't reset?
2016-11-28 16:06:23.090  b         4 
2016-11-28 16:09:07.200  c         5
2016-12-10 11:21:55.807  c         6
```

And now i randomly type things - frantic flailing.

```
SELECT 
   Date, TheThing, 
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY(CASE WHEN TheThing IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date

SELECT 
   Date, TheThing, 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY(CASE WHEN TheThing IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date
```

**Edit**: With all the answers, it took many iterations to find all the edge cases that i **don't** want. In the end what i conceptually wanted was `OVER()` in order to *count*. I had no idea `OVER` applied to anything other than `RANK` (and `DENSE_RANK`).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6d87/1

### Bonus Reading

- [How to use RANK() in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739208/how-to-use-rank-in-sql-server)
- [RANK without counting nulls](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/deb8a0aa-aaab-442b-a667-11220333a4e0/rank-without-counting-null-values?forum=transactsql)
- [SQL Server 2012 PERCENT_RANK() Exclude NULLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091149/sql-server-2012-percent-rank-exclude-nulls)
- [Exclude null values using DENSE_RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984393/exclude-null-values-using-dense-rank)

Comment: I don't think if you can do this in a single query. First you need to filter the records for not Nulls and then select all with the ranks that has been created previously.

Comment: Is `TheThing` ever anything other than `Frob` or `null`? Does that affect the running total? Please show all edge cases.

Comment: Does `Rank()` with `case when TheThing is NULL then Lag ... else TheThing end` to use the prior row's value get you anywhere? It may need a fudge factor to handle an initial `null` value should that occur.

Comment: @HABO or two NULLs in a row, since LAG() would have to be aware of not a constant but rather how many rows back is the last non-NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for a cumulative count:

```
SELECT Date, TheThing, 
       COUNT(theThing) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM MyData
ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: It won't work the same as `RANK` nor as `DENSE_RANK` when you introduce ties. And is almost the same as first query in my answer :) and that was pointed to me as well :)

Comment: While all the other answer are good, and will work for other people trying to solve another problem, the actual problem i wanted solving indeed was *"counting"*. I thought `RANK OVER` ***was*** the way to count. Turns out `COUNT OVER` is something new.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table (dt datetime, col int);
insert into @tbl values
('2016-03-09 08:17:29.867', 1),
('2016-03-09 08:18:33.327', 1),
('2016-03-09 14:32:01.240', NULL),
('2016-10-21 19:53:49.983', NULL),
('2016-11-12 03:25:21.753', 1),
('2016-11-24 07:43:24.483', NULL),
('2016-11-28 16:06:23.090', 1),
('2016-11-28 16:09:07.200', 1),
('2016-12-10 11:21:55.807', 1);

select dt,
       col,
       sum(case when col is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dt) rnk
from @tbl
```

The idea is really simple: if you assign 1 to non-null values and zero where the column is null, cumulative sum ordered by date is works exactly as rank excluding nulls.

Other way would be to use `RANK` combined with `ROW_NUMBER`, which will respect ties in `Date` column and works exactly as `RANK` respecting `NULL`s:

```
select dt,
       col,
       case when col is not null then 
           rank() over (order by dt)
       else 
           rank() over (order by dt) - row_number() over (partition by rnDiff order by dt)
       end rnk
from (
    select dt,
           col,
           row_number() over (order by dt) -
               row_number() over (partition by coalesce(col, 0) order by dt) rnDiff
    from @tbl
) a
order by dt
```

Comment: this doesnt handle duplicates as RANK would

Comment: though possibly they were on the wrong track with RANK anyway. But the difference will be seen for example if multiple values exist tied with the lowest dt. RANK would assign all 1. This wont.

Comment: Actually, it will assign rank correctly, but instead of 1, there would be 2 (in casse of two tied rows), but it would be the same for tied rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Second query handles ties correctly, but I think (from presented data) that first query would be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

My lizard brain brings me here... sum() over vs rank()

```
Select *
       ,NewCol = sum(sign(TheThing)) over (Order by Date)
       ,OrEven = sum(TheThing/TheThing) over (Order by Date)  
 From  MyData
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about subtracting the current count of `NULL`s from the `rank()`?

```
SELECT date,
       thething,
       rank() OVER (ORDER BY date)
       -
       sum(CASE
             WHEN thething IS NULL THEN
               1
             ELSE
               0
           END) OVER (ORDER BY date) desiredtotal
       FROM mydata;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3d3660c2c20b2a39c2b86d88a22d15be)

That should also keep the duplicates and gaps `rank()` produces and doesn't need a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `subquery` :

```
SELECT [Date], TheThing,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyData m
        WHERE m.[Date] <= m1.[Date] AND m.TheThing IS NOT NULL
       ) AS DesiredTotal
FROM MyData m1;
```

In, similar way you can also try with `apply` :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyData m1 CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DesiredTotal
     FROM MyData m
     WHERE m.[Date] <= m1.[Date] AND m.TheThing IS NOT NULL
    ) m2;
```

Comment: This will work but it's very sensitive to size of data... be wary of exponential runtimes on larger data sets.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. . . I know this is not an efficient way to generate the series.

Answer (score 0):

I used a CTE to get the right date first and then applied the rank to the modified date:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(dt datetime, TheThing int)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-03-09 08:17:29.867',  1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-03-09 08:18:33.327',  1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-03-09 14:32:01.240',  NULL)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-10-21 19:53:49.983',  NULL)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-11-12 03:25:21.753',  1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-11-24 07:43:24.483',  NULL)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-11-28 16:06:23.090',  1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-11-28 16:09:07.200',  1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2016-12-10 11:21:55.807',  1)


;WITH CTE as (
SELECT 
CASE WHEN TheThing IS NULL THEN (SELECT MAX(dt) from #tmp OrigTbl where OrigTbl.dt <     SubTbl.dt and OrigTbl.TheThing IS NOT NULL) ELSE dt end dtMod,
SubTbl.dt,SubTbl.TheThing
   from #tmp SubTbl)
SELECT dt, TheThing, DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY dtMod) from CTE
```